# Ruby - Watir Saving File with a custom file name

Tags: ruby, watir

If I have the below HTML:

```
<a class="name" title="file_name" href="/somelink>NAMEOFFILE</a>
    <div class="profile">
    <img class="FFVAD" decoding="auto" style="" sizes="496px" src="https://websitename.com/054a89a69181e68399c756d746f3b996/followme.jpg">
    </div>
```

How do use Watir to save download and save the image using the link title.
So file followme.jpg, would be downloaded and saved as title_name.jpg

Comment: When you click that link , `save as` window dialog opens?

Comment: essentially, I just need to get download the image and then save the file as the title name. The download image bit I think I can do it's my the ruby save file function with custom name I'm unsure of.

Comment: File gets automatically downloaded when you click the link? Once after downloaded you need to rename the file?

Comment: Okay thanks. Your other question doesnt express any condition in which WATIR is being the concerns, it appears to be purely Ruby question.

Comment: It was, again apologies. I had seen that there was a Watir-get-image gem which had been used in the past. Which is why I put that in there. I ended up using open-uri instead to call the src. (I've amended my other question and removed watir)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I figured this one out in the end. I stored the title of the element into a string, then used the string when calling the file write.

```
 @image_src = @browser.div(:class => "profile").image(:class => "FFVAD").src
    @userimage = @browser.link(:class => "name").text
          @filename = "./folder/#{@userimage}.jpg"

    File.open(@filename, 'wb') do |f|
             f.write open(@image_src).read
           end
```